# When is the sum of all the projection matrices of a matrix equal to the identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix A and I decompose it into projections onto its eigenspaces $P_{i}$ ($A=\sum_i\lambda_{i}P_{i}$).

If the sum of all the projection matrices of a matrix is equal to the identity matrix $\sum_{i}P_{i} = I$, what does that tell me about A?

Comment: In case 0 is an eigenvalue the corresponding term is not present in the expansion. Thus if the sum is the identity then the null space of $A$ is empty and $A$ is invertible.

Comment: What do you meant by "projection"? Are these necessarily orthogonal projections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how exactly you define the $P_i$ (since there could be more than one projection onto a subspace). However, if you're doing what I think you're doing, then the $P_i$ will add to the identity iff $A$ is diagonalizable.